# Trick playing iis smooth streaming (.ism) in android

Tags: android, azure, smooth-streaming

I'm developing a software which should play videos from Azure Media Service, which are in format .ism. 
I know that this format isn't supported by standrard Android video player.

What is the most efficient way to trick this?

Videos could be more than 2gb therefore converting on the go is bad decision. Also I have found another (not standard) player but it costs money (also bad variant).

Probably there's some suitable library to play such videos?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what makes you think converting on the go is bad decision? Before all, it is not converting on the go, it is just packing on the go. But please set a concrete question related to programming, list what you have tried and why it doesn't work. Then you will get proper help here.

Comment: Juste for my knowledge, what's the name of the paying player ?

Comment: @astaykov And what if I convert that video right before play. Doesn't it influence on perfomance slightly? You see, I'm trying to find the most efficient way whether its convertion or another player, or maybe smth else.

Comment: @AnZyuZya read (with understanding) the following invaluable resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj889436.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Google released ExoPlayer with is exactly what you need for playing smooth streaming video. It's still in development but work well.

**ExoPlayer Official page** : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Comment: That library does really work with smooth streaming. BUT there is a problem. Streams with codecs or encryptions could be played on 18 API and higher only. And that takes only 20% of phones. 
On previous versions it can play only CLEAR smooth streaming videos.

Answer (score 0):

The native android VideoView can't play this format. In order to play it, you'll have to create you're own decoder and you're own hardware accelerated library's 
I don't think that is an option (money whise)

To play it, you'll have to convert it to a different format. It is possible using silverlight, but Android doesn't support silverlight so that's a no-go